# Слишком сложно или слишком легко скрипт для Google таблиц

Tags: google-spreadsheet, макросы

Есть таблица, 10 столбцов и 3 строки (может быть сколько угодно)
В строках выбираются значения из выпадающего списка это или **В** или **Р** или **Д**.
Как с помощью скрипта сделать так, чтоб например выбрав в строке 1 в столбце 5 значение **В**, то всё что идет до 5 столбца проставилось автоматически значение **В** или же сделав тоже самое в столбце 10, автоматом проставилось значение **В** с 1 по 9 стобец, не зависимо какие значение находились в этих ячейках до этого.
Но если например уже заполнены значения **В** с 1 по 4 столбец, а остальные с 5 по 10 столбцы свободны, при выборе например значения **Р** в 7 столбце, автоматом менялись только пустые значения т.е. в столбцах с 5 по 7 проставлялись значения **Р**.
Получается что значение **В** может менять любые значения, а значение **Р** все, кроме значений **В**. Заранее спасибо за помощь. 
Извините если плохо объяснил.

[image: Как то так выглядит таблица]

Comment: Ребят помогите пожалуйста, пробовал адаптировать скрипт который добавляет автоматом даты, но не хватает знаний.